# How do I get Sonic Mania's true ending?

Tags: sonic-mania

I just finished Sonic Mania after collecting all 7 Chaos Emeralds as Knuckles. Despite getting every Emerald, my game ended after beating the Phantom Egg in Titanic Monarch.

I'm a bit confused why collecting all 7 Emeralds didn't let me fight Mania's secret final boss for the [good ending](http://gameranx.com/features/id/115636/article/sonic-mania-how-to-fight-the-secret-final-boss-true-ending-guide/).

**How do I get the true ending in Sonic Mania?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question is still open, I'll expand our comments into an answer.

**You have to be playing as Sonic to get the "good" ending.**

This might make sense, as the link in your question says that:

> the "good" ending is actually a lead-in to [Sonic Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_Forces), which features "classic" Sonic alongside the more modern 3D version.

This theory is echoed in the following links:

- [Well, THAT ending!!!! Spoilers...](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/193353-sonic-mania/75662492_)
- [(Huge Sonic Mania Spoilers) The implications of Sonic Mania's Ending](https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendo/comments/6t8b4q/huge_sonic_mania_spoilers_the_implications_of/)
- [THEORY: Is Sonic Mania's True Ending...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OETLvSZWZk)
- [So... About that true ending... (spoilers!)](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204239-sonic-mania/75676182)

Also note that you can get the "good" ending when playing as Sonic and Tails or as Sonic with & Knuckles mode enabled as well.